# How to deploy an EAR on Apache TomEE with classloader set parent last?

Tags: java, deployment, ear, apache-tomee

For Apache TomEE (https://tomee.apache.org/), not Tomcat, how to configure it to deploy an EAR to apps with the classloader set to **Parent Last**?

Comment: Already have that working.  The problem is the classloader loads **Parent First** and getting exceptions all over the place during runtime.  The question was how to do it with classloader set to **Parent Last**.

Comment: Could you refer this? http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-classloader-configuration-td4656233.html

Comment: Nothing in the that thread except a dirty hack of the expanded folder.  

Looks like this is going to be a show stopper for using TomEE.  Will have to use something like IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile which allows such configuration of the classloader.

Comment: you can configure in conf/system.properties openejb.classloader.forced-load=some.package1,some.package2,... to enforce tomee to try to load in the lower classloader first the packages.